# Lenovo Thinkpad T520 doesn't boot from Ubuntu 15.10 Installation USB Stick

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb, usb-creator

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 from my Intenso 32GB USB-stick on my Lenovo Thinkpad T520.

I created a USB-Stick with the tool linked at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows.

I choose to format the USB-Stick with Fat32.

I cound't verify that the USB-stick was built successfully, since I'm not able to boot from USB with my other Laptop either, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't have been be created successfully.

I can't select the USB-stick from the BIOS boot-menu, so I think that's the problem. Changing the boot-priority of USB-HDD USB-CD etc. didn't help with booting either.

I already read [ThinkPad T520 won't boot from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297553/thinkpad-t520-wont-boot-from-usb?rq=1). As I understood it, his problem was the type of usb-stick or the brand. I don't know if my usb-stick is compatible with my bios and I also don't know how I can find it out either.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

since you can't boot from the usb-drive on 2 machines, there seems to be a problem with either the iso file itself or the way it is written to the usb-drive.

To check the integrity of the iso file, follow the steps here:

[How to MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

(section MD5SUM on Windows)

the MD5SUMS to compare can be found here:

[MD5SUMS for ubuntu 15.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/wily/MD5SUMS)

If the MD5SUMS do not match, redownload the iso and check MD5SUMS again.
If the MD5SUMS match, you could try to use a different software to write the iso to your usb drive, for example

[unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

if that fails too, using a different USB-drive or a DVD might do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! Yh, I already managed to install Ubuntu with a DVD on this Laptop, however the DVD seems to be broken. So eventually I may have to buy a bunch of DVDs if I don't find another solution.

I'll also try to use a different usb-stick and the boot-creator that you referenced. I think this seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

unetbootin and the usb-creator don't work for xubuntu, kubuntu and ubuntu 15.10 for me either. If you have windows, you can use pendrivelinux's universal usb installer to create a usb boot disk.